# How can I use a select box in a form and submit the selected value?

Tags: php, html

I have a form with an input field. It works very well. When I write something into the input field and click submit, the value is stored into my database:

```
<form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post">     
    <input name="option" type="text" value="<?php echo !empty($option)?$option:'';?>">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But I don't need an input field, I need a select box instead. I tried this, but it is not working:

```
  <form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post">    
     <select>
       <?php
          $default = "No";
          $options = array("Yes","No");
          foreach($options as $val) {
            echo ($val == $default) ? "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"$val\">$val</option>":"<option value=\"$val\">$val</option>";
          }
       ?>
   </select>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Do you have an idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Your `select` does not have a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing `name` in `select`

```
<select name="option">
       <?php
          $default = "No";
          $options = array("Yes","No");
          foreach($options as $val) {
            echo ($val == $default) ? "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"$val\">$val</option>":"<option value=\"$val\">$val</option>";
          }
       ?>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `name` attribute of `select` input.

```
<select name="option">
```

You can access it by -

```
$_POST['option'] // for POST method
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // sample code if you need call the value from database here for static value
  <form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post" > 

  <select name="option">

    <option value="PHP" <?php if($options=="PHP") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >PHP</option>

 </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not working. I tried:
 `<select name="option">

    <option value="yes" <?php if($options=="yes") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >yes</option>
    <option value="no" <?php if($options=="nein") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >no</option>
 </select>` It is not submitting the selected value

Comment: hi... may i know what is your value of $options .. i had given same code in my ans .. first you get the value from table and stored in $options variable...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer:

```
<select name="option">
<option <?php if ($option == Yes ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option <?php if ($option == No ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="No">No</option>
</select>
```